# Create proxy for Apache CXF Web services in wso2 ESB

Tags: cxf, wso2-esb

I am a very beginner in `ESB`. So, kindly excuse me for this basic question.

Currently we have web services created with `Apache CXF` and `Spring` running. Now, we need to create proxy services for these in `WSo2 ESB`. Can someone please let us know how can we do this?

I created `Pass Through` proxy and use `wsdl` definition as from URL, but when i use try it option i get he endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is `/services/` and the `WSA Action = null`.

If this `EPR` was previously reachable,please contact the server administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Since ESB 4.6, pass-through transport is enabled by default : The message body is not build so, SOAP Body based dispatching is not supported => in this case, the error you're speaking about is thrown

One solution could be to add this parameter in your proxy conf : `<parameter name="disableOperationValidation" locked="false">true</parameter>`

Have a look there for other options : [Using WSO2 ESB PassThrough Proxy on WebLogic (Spring) Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584536/using-wso2-esb-passthrough-proxy-on-weblogic-spring-web-service/23602518#23602518)

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the proxy service? If you have the wsdl of the Backend service you can use it to create the proxy service like follows.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="testProxy2" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <wsdl service="SimpleStockQuoteService"
               port="SimpleStockQuoteServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint"
               uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

The ESB gets the endpoint url from the [Service name](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_services) and [Port](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_ports) defined in the WSDL. For SOAP 1.1 the WSA action will be the SOAPAction header and for SOAP 1.2 the WSA action goes with the action element of Content-Type header. For example,

```
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="TheSoapAction"
```

Try to use a SOAP client like SOAPUI to test your proxy service.